# What is the initial number of partitions created for a dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, parallel-processing, partitioning

I am new to Spark. I am trying to understand the number of partitions produced by default by a `hiveContext.sql("query")` statement. I know that we can `repartition` the `dataframe` after it has been created using `df.repartition`. But, what is the number of partitions produced by default when the `dataframe` is initially created?

I understand that `sc.parallelize` and some other transformations produce the number of partitions according to `spark.default.parallelism`. But what about a `dataframe` ? I saw some answers saying that the setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` produces the set number of partitions while doing shuffle operations like join. Does this give the initial number of partitions when a dataframe is created?

Then I also saw some answers explaining the number of partitions produced by setting

```
mapred.min.split.size.
mapred.max.split.size and
hadoop block size
```

Then when I tried to do it practically, I read 10 million records into a dataframe in a spark-shell launched with 2 executors and 4 cores per executor. When I did `df.rdd.getNumPartitions`, I get the value `1`. How am I getting 1 for the number of partitions? isn't `2` the min number of partitions?

When I do a count on the `dataframe`, I see that 200 tasks are being launched. IS this due to the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` setting?

I am totally confused! can someone please answer my questions?? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think that "hiveContext.sql("query")" really depends on the data source that gives the partitioning / bucketing metadata that is used to create a dataset. What's the query you're exploring? A hive table? What are the settings of Spark SQL?

Comment: The query is just a sample query I am running to understand the number of partitions it creates by default like `select * from limit n;`. I am running the query on a hive table. What do you mean by settings of Spark SQL? @JacekLaskowski

Comment: "Spark SQL settings" == configuration properties in `conf/spark-defaults.conf` + `spark-submit` + env vars

Comment: `spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars=${env:HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/../hive/lib/*:${env:HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/client/*

spark.sql.hive.metastore.version=1.1.0

spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive` These are the only settings I found for spark sql in `spark-defaults.conf` . I was running the code in `spark-shell` with 2 executors and 4 cores per executor. No other confs were set. @JacekLaskowski